# PHP add 24 hours to a specific date

Tags: php, datetime

I need to add 24 hours to a date that will be stored in a variable.

Example:

`$date = "2019-11-20 05:05:00"; => $date = "2019-11-21 05:05:00";` (24 hours have been added).

I've tried some options, but I haven't been successful in any of them.

I have tried with `strtotime()` method:

```
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+24 hours')).
```

If the sintaxe is like above, then it works, but it doesn't seem to accept a pre-defined date or a variable, like this:

```
$date = "2019-11-20 05:05:00";
$new_time = date($date, strtotime('+24 hours'));
```

Or this:

```
$new_time = date("2019-11-20 05:05:00", strtotime('+24 hours'));
```

In both cases the output is the same as the input date, without the +24 being added.

I've experimented the `modify()` method.

```
$date = "2019-11-20 05:05:00";

$dateTime= new DateTime($date);
$dateTime->modify('+24 hours');

print_r($dateTime);

echo $datetime->date;
```

Output (if I print the objetct):

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-11-21 05:05:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Paris
)

2019-11-21 05:05:00.000000
```

Output (if I don't print the objetct):

```
Notice:  Undefined property: DateTime::$date
```

It sort of works, but the problem is that I can access the date property only if I print the whole `dateTime object`, what would trouble my application. Besides that, apparently, these properties don't really exist, they seem to be more like a bug, since they are not described in the documentation as properties of the `dateTime object`.

I am trying to use `getTimestamp()`, but I couldn't add time to it.

How could I do that?

Comment: You can't, and shouldn't, access the `date` attribute directly. Use the `format` method instead. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHP manual has a complete example;

```php
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

The value for `DateInterval` could be changed In 'PT24H'. During daylight savings changes 24 hours is not the same as 1 day, which PHP will arrange for you with the proper timezone configuration.

Comment: About daylight savings, is it possible to cancel this in PHP? I'm asking because here in Brazil, since this year it doesn't exist anymore, but PHP is still considering it.

Comment: Usually the timezone database is not compiled with PHP, but linked from the operating system. Check the output of `phpinfo()` to see how it is setup on your system, which should direct you how to update it.

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you very much again.

Comment: perhaps typo and `new DateInterval('P10D')` should be `new DateInterval('P1D')` ?

Comment: @Jimmix The 'P10D' is from the example in the manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php#example-2760).
In this instance 'PT24H' should be used for 24 hours as stated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, all you have to do is create an interval and then use `add` method. Like so:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval("P0Y0M0DT24H0M0S");
$dateTime->add($interval);
```